# Accessing Qt tableView from MyModel

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview

(Linux Mint QT5) I subclassed **QAbstractTableModel** to use a custom **sort()** function after **tableView.setModel(MyModel)**...

```cpp
class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{   Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyModel(QTableView *_tableview);    // sort() function needs to access the linked tableview
... (more function definitions)
    void sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order) override;
private:
QTableView *tableview;  // <<<======== Don't know how to avoid passing and storing this pointer
};

MyModel::MyModel(QTableView *_tableview) : QAbstractTableModel(0)
{
tableview=_tableview;
... (more constructor code)
}

void MyModel::sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order)
{
int uniq=data(tableview->currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(4), Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
sort_redirection_table(column, order);  // sort pointers into data, not the data itself
for (int row=emk->ct; row--; ) // now re-locate current row
    if ((data(QAbstractTableModel::index(row, 4), Qt::DisplayRole)).toInt()==uniq)
        {
        tableview->scrollTo(QAbstractTableModel::index(row, column),QTreeView::PositionAtCenter);
        tableview->selectRow(row);  // make tableView re-focus around same item as before sorting
        break;
        }
}
```

Note that **MyModel::data()** accesses the underlying data through a sorted array of *pointers*. Every (int) value in column 4 is unique, so I'm using **currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(4)** from the linked **tableView** to see which line item was selected *before* the sort, because I need to re-centre the display around that line *after* sorting.

---

My code seems to work fine, but I can't help feeling it's "inelegant" to pass the **tableView** pointer to **MyModel** constructor, storing it for later use when re-focusing the display after sorting.

This is my first Qt project, so I'm certainly no expert! I started with dummy copies of **MyProject/main.cpp, mymodel.cpp, mymodel.h**  against which I ran **qmake -project** followed by **qmake MyProject.pro** to create **makefile**. So far I'm only using QtCreator to edit/compile my own "bare metal" code (I haven't even *looked* at GUI design mode facilities yet).

Am I missing something trivial about **MyModel**'s access to the linked **tableView**? Is there any easy way to re-focus the display *without* that stored pointer? Or some way to get the pointer without having it passed to the constructor? Or am I simply mistaken in thinking my current code is 'inelegant'?

Answer (score 1):

Complex question, but I'm going to try to shed some light on different aspects.

0. `currentIndex` and the selection are two separate (but not unrelated) things. Make sure you understand the difference when working with both.
1. You are trying to sort an item model. In my experience, it is always best to not do that in the actual item model, but use or extend a `QSortFilterProxyModel`.
2. Your sort function is missing a few things: Signals for the view, and persistent index updates. By default, `QSortFilterProxyModel` handles all that for you. The [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20220121064951/https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#resizable-models) lists these actions:

> - Emit the layoutAboutToBeChanged() signal
> - Update internal data which represents the structure of the model.
> - Update persistent indexes using changePersistentIndexList()
> - Emit the layoutChanged() signal.

3. You don't have to access the table view from the model. That's what signals are for. If you don't find any other solution, you can always define a new `sorted` signal in the model and then connect to some function that scrolls to the element outside of the model.
4. Putting most of this together, here is an example on what you could do. If the default sorting isn't sophisticated enough, extend `QSortFilterProxyModel` and use that instead. The following would be somewhere in the setup of the widget that contains the table view:

```
    MyModel* myModel = new MyModel(tableView);
    QSortFilterProxyModel* proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(tableView);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(myModel);
    tableView->setModel(proxyModel);
    connect(proxyModel, &QSortFilterProxyModel::layoutChanged, tableView, [tableView]()
    {
        tableView->scrollTo(tableView->currentIndex());
    });
```

Comment: I initially started with a QSortFilterProxyModel  (copied from either basic- or customsortfiltermodel Qt example, I can't remember which). As I recall, I didn't seem to need to actually override **sort()** for that - just implement a **less_than()** function. But eventually I hit much the same problem as described here. I had to subclass **MyQSortFilterProxyModel** purely so I could override **sort()** there as well. For the same reason - eventually it seemed that my subclass needed a pointer to the basic **tableView**, just so I could refocus the display after sorting....

Comment: ...anyway, thanks for this detailed response. It's a lot for me to take in. As yet, I have no experience and very little understanding of aspects of Qt programming involving the keywords "connect", "emit", and "signal", except insofar as they existed in the sortfilterproxymodel example programs I looked at before I started trying to write my own code. There are no such keywords in my own code yet. But I'm getting old and slow, so it may be *days* before I've understood your answer well enough to know how to ask for any clarifications I might need! Unless/until then, I'll just repeat my thanks!

Comment: NEXT DAY... Memories are hazy, but I think the reason I didn't include a QSortFilterProxyModel in my original code was probably because I didn't understand how it worked in the basic- and customsortfiltermodel Qt examples that I was "cribbing" from to get started/ Specifically, I mistakenly thought including the proxy inevitably forced the display to show my table in a "window within a window", which I figured was wasting too much valuable screen space! Anyway, thanks to your suggestions, I've included the proxy (and blindly copied / adapted your "connect" line). AND IT WORKS!  ....

Comment: I have't yet overridden the actual sort process. The custom sort routine in MyModel never gets called, so for now the proxy is just doing its dumb default character sort, but I'm expecting to be able to resolve that myself in a day or two. The key point is that "re-focus the display" problem is now entirely handled within the sortProxy, and *I don't have to know or care* about using that pointer to the **tableView** object. That was what bothered me in the first place, and led to me asking for help here....

Comment: So far as I can see, the true answer to my final question in the post *(Am I simply mistaken in thinking my current code is 'inelegant'?)* is simply ***Yes** - I was mistaken*. These are complex things for me to get my head around, but my specific takeaway here is that *something* has to maintain a link between the display logicand the sorting logic. I was iffy about my model constructor remembering that tableView pointer for later re-focusing of display after sort. Although I'm not explicitly doing it myself now, the proxy is doing it "under the hood" anyway. But I feel I'm getting somewhere!

Comment: Your feeling was correct, and the proxy model isn't doing it either. It merely publishes (as in to everyone, possibly) a signal that it changed. That is completely valid. The table doesn't know that it should re-scroll either. The connection code that is neither in the table nor in a model, does that.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. In fact, I've now completed implementation of a proxy as per your suggestion. Which was a bit confusing at first, because it looks as if some functions can be implemented in *either* the model or the proxy. Initially I tried to implement everything in the proxy, but eventually I reduced it to only override **sort()**. But I couldn't get any of that "connect", "emit", and "signal" stuff working, so I'm still passing a pointer to the underlying tableView (to the proxy rather than the model, now) to re-focus the display. Your answer has been a great help, though, ty.

Comment: You shouldn't have to override the sort funciton. If you do that, you can just use the model again. And you have do to all the things mentioned in 2. manually. If you just override the less_than function, the proxy model will handle all that for you.

Comment: You certainly seem to be good at picking out the key points here! In my very first attempt at implementing my project, I did in fact use less_than() - and if I recall, it *correctly* handled the business of *remembering previous sequence* when sorting different columns (so equal keys in the newly-sorted column *always* get listed in the immediately-preceding sequence, which lots of software fails to do). I think I switched to sort() because it seemed clunky having to sort on the crude basis of the character display contents of a column (as opposed to the *actual* underlying binary data).

Comment: But I now feel confident that I can go back and switch out *sort()* in favour of *less_than()* for my "final" version! If that's the way to go, the sooner I get used to it the better!

Comment: You have access to model indexes in `lessThan`. A model index can return any data. So what I do in such cases is define a new role (`public: static constexpr int MyPointerRole = Qt::UserRole + 1337`, where 1337 is some random number), and just return the pointer to the object in the row for that role in my model's `data` function (using `QVariant::fromValue`). In the `lessThan` function I can then work with the pointer: `MyPointer* ptr = source_left.data(MyPointerRole).value<MyPointer*>();`. Not ideal, but fits Qt's model. In my opinion the item models are one of the weakest features in Qt.

Comment: Everything has now come together nicely, thanks to your pointers. As it happens, the only slight niggle I still have in this area is about (data structure) pointers. I tried and failed to get MyModel::data((row, columnNumberContaining UNIQUE value), Qt::Userrole) to return a ***pointer*** to the underlying data structure. For the time being I'm settling for retrieving the **sourceModel()->data(a.siblingAtColumn(UniqColumn)).toInt()** unique value, and doing a lookup to find that key value in my table. QT doesn't like my data() function returning a pointer to *anything!*

Comment: You might have to cast it to a void pointer or register the pointer type with QVariant first, I'm not sure what it was right now. If your object is a QObject, you can also cast it to `QObject*`, that should work without issue.

Comment: The data object is my own binary record structure. For now, I'm happy that within **lessThan()** I can retrieve pointers to the **left*** and **right** records under[pinning the passed params. I tried using **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyRecordSructure)**, but couldn't get it to work quickly, so I switched to doing a hand-coded lookup. But I might well ask here for more help if I still can't manage that after a few more goes. I'm *really* happy with how little code I need to write with the revised methodology you steered me towards, so I can't thank you enough. **MANY THANKS**!